# How to get current active stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
var text:TextField = new TextField();
text.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
getCurrentActiveStage().focus = text;
```

Comment: No because an instance not added to any stage can not be focused. Once it's added, if `getCurrentActiveStage()` function returns a Stage, then yes.

Comment: My question is "how can I get this stage?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any display object added to the display chain in some way, you can reference it through the `stage` property. So, if `text` is already on the stage, just call:

```
text.stage.focus = text;
```

If not, you can't access the stage without some reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access stage from any place by `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage`